# Como eliminar los brackets en un string?

Tags: javascript

Con este código busco en una `string` los **indices** de `"["` y de `"]"` y luego elimino lo que está dentro de ellos con un `replace`, pero también necesito **eliminar los corchetes**, como debo hacerlo? , porque no los elimina en mi ejemplo...

```js
var a = "Hola[x]fsaaf fsa";

var b = a.indexOf("["); 
var c = a.indexOf("]"); 
var mostrar = a.substring(b, c +1);
var name = a.replace(new RegExp(mostrar, 'g'), "");

console.log(name);
```

Además intente, algo que nosé mucho lo que significa, esto:

```
var a = "Hola[x]fsaaf fsa";

var b = a.indexOf("["); // 6
var c = a.indexOf("]"); // 16
var mostrar = a.substring(b, c +1);
var name = a.replace(regex, "");
var  regex = new RegExp('\\[?\\b(?:' + mostrar + ')\\b\\]?', 'gi');
console.log(name);
```

Pero me deja toda la string igual..

Comment: Explica un poco más qué es lo que quieres, por un string de ejemplo y lo que esperas obtener. Me parece entender que quieres sustituir lo que haya entre corchetes por otro string, es asi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otra solución más óptima, para el parser sería hacer

```js
var regExp = /\[[^\[\]]+\]/g
var mensaje = 'Hola[x] mundo[xasf234][a]'
var resultado = mensaje.match(regExp)
   
for(i in resultado) {
    resultado[i] = resultado[i].replace(/[\[\]]/g,'') //sanitiza el resultado
}

console.log(mensaje)
console.log(mensaje.replace(regExp,''))
console.log(resultado)
```

Comment: Eduen, pero antes necesito usar además lo que está dentro de los corchetes, no solo eliminarlos

Comment: entonces primero debes utilizar .match, antes de reemplazar.

Answer (score 1):

Lo logré en dos lineas:

```js
var a = "Hola[x]fsaaf fsa";

var b = a.indexOf("["); 
var c = a.indexOf("]"); 
var mostrar = a.substring(b, c +1);
var name = a.replace(new RegExp(mostrar, 'g'), "");
name = name.replace(/[\[\]']+/g,'');

console.log(name);
```

En una linea:

```js
var a = "Hola[x]fsaaf fsa";
var name = a.replace(/\[.*?\]/g, '')
console.log(name);

a = "Hola[x] mundo[xasf234][a]";
name = a.replace(/\[.*?\]/g, '')
console.log(name);
```

Comment: @ReneLimon solo la mención de que utilizar \s, elimina los espacios, y en la medida de lo posible, hay que preservar todo el texto excepto los brackets.